# Time Frequency Color Map

Tags: python, matplotlib, frequency, color-mapping

I'd like to show the occurrence in a color map for the frequency of a point , i.e. (1,2) has a frequency of 3 points while still keeping my 'xaxis' (i.e. df['A'])

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,6,7,7],
                   'B': [2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8]})
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'])
plt.show()
```

Here is my current plot

[image: Here]

I'd like to keep the same axis I have, while adding the colormap. Hope I was being clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the frequency of a certain value using the `collections` package.

```
freq_dic = collections.Counter(df["B"])
```

You then need to add this new list to your dataframe and add two new options to the scatter plot. The colormap legend is displayed with plt.colorbar. This code is far from perfect, so any further improvements are very welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,6,7,7],
                   'B': [2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8]})

freq_dic = collections.Counter(df["B"])


for index, entry in enumerate(df["B"]):
    df.at[index, 'freq'] = (freq_dic[entry])


plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'],
            c=df['freq'],
            cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]